# Qual a origem da expressões e o seu verdadeiro significado: "vai de vela" ou "ir de vela"?

Tags: significado, expressões, origem-histórica, ditados

Qual a origem da expressão e o seu verdadeiro significado: "vai de vela" ou "ir de vela"?

Já ouvi no sentido o "João foi de vela"
Será que significa que perdeu algo?
Quem perde vai de vela ?

Comment: Podia-se perguntar o significado, ou qual a origem da expressão. Assim como está, parecem duas perguntas distintas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É uma expressão utilizada na modalidade oral do Português (PE), em contextos informais, em diálogos com pessoas próximas ou que partilham o mesmo estilo discursivo. O significado significa "ir embora", "desaparecer"; Também adquire o sentido de "perder alguma coisa" quando utilizamos no seguinte contexto:
Quando duas pessoas estão a conversar sobre os concorrentes de um determinado jogo e um deles diz:
"- O João foi de vela!" (= saiu do jogo / perdeu o jogo)

Answer (score 1):

Bom, a expressão surgiu na França Feudal.
Ela era utilizada para o jovem (criado) segurar "luminárias" (na época: candeeiros) para que os seus patrões tivessem relações sexuais iluminadas. E, agora, utilizamos essa expressão quando há um (ou mais) casal (is) e um solteiro (a) no meio da galera.

Comment: Penso que a sua resposta é mais adequada para a expressão "segurar a vela", neste caso a pergunta é sobre "ir de vela"

Comment: Pode verificar?

Answer (score 0):

Após mais algumas pesquisas , efetivamente encontrei que ir de vela significa , "ir embora" "desaparecer"

ir de vela
• [Informal]  Ir embora, desaparecer.

https://dicionario.priberam.org/vela

ve·la |é|1
(latim vela, -orum, plural de velum, -i, pano, reposteiro, cortina, véu, máscara)
nome feminino

1. Pano forte e resistente que se prende aos mastros para fazer andar as embarcações, ou aos braços dos moinhos de vento para os fazer girar.Ver imagem
2. [Figurado]  Embarcação dotada desse pano e movida pela força do vento.
3. [Desporto]  Modalidade desportiva que compreende disciplinas com embarcações dotadas de vela.
4. [Astronomia]  Constelação austral. (Geralmente com inicial maiúscula.)

à vela
• Com as velas desfraldadas.

• [Informal]  Em fralda de camisa.

• [Informal]  Sem roupa. = DESCOBERTO, DESPIDO

ir de vela
• [Informal]  Ir embora, desaparecer.

vela de balão
• [Náutica]  Grande vela de proa triangular, leve e côncava, utilizada em veleiros de recreio nas mareações a partir de bolina folgada. = BALÃO

vela latina
• [Náutica]  Vela, triangular ou quadrangular, que tem um dos lados preso ao mastro ou mastaréu.

vela redonda

"vela", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/vela [consultado em 08-04-2021].

Answer (score 0):

No Nordeste usamos essa expressão quando um solteiro, vai junto com um casal. Então vai segurar vela pro casal.

Comment: Também usamos isso em SP. Mas isso seria porque "vela" significa isso aí, tipo "fui de vela pro encontro deles" e "fui vela no encontro deles". "Ir de vela" já tem um significado a mais em si. Tua resposta é boa de qualquer modo, porque isso é uma interpretação possível. +1

Comment: ai a expressão é segurar a vela, o quer é algo diferente.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui em São Paulo usamos esse termo quando um solteiro vai sair junto de um casal, pois a pessoa solteira ficara "sobrando"